# Using D3 Data is loaded from a csv file but the path is not being drawn

Tags: d3.js, path

I am trying to plot a track of all the railway stations in Overijssel.
I am trying to load data from a "csv" file and then plot the path. In the Developer tools under the "Elements" tag when I check it, it shows that path data is loaded, the path is not showing in the view mode.

Code:

```
d3.csv("test.csv").get(function(data){
    //console.log(data[1]);
    var svg=d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height","100%")
    .attr("width","100%");
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("d",data[0].path)
        .attr("class","area")
        .attr("fill","steelblue")

});
```

[The image show the browser development tool, where it can be seen that the data is loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PLjb.png)

Comment: You're example is not reproductible. first thing, you'are only plotting one point : `data[0].path` please look here https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js. you need to use `d3.svg.line()` as in the example

Comment: There is no error here, you are drawing a path that has negative values in its coordinates (not to mention values with high magnitude), the feature is located outside the bounds of your svg. How did you create the data?

Comment: @timat i don't have the data in that format. I am reading the data from a csv file.

Comment: @AndrewReid i didn't create the data. I got it from someone. it was already created.